# Post Request for Api Rest in android application

Tags: java, android, json, rest, http-post

Good morning, everyone. I hope everything's all right with you. I have a concern that since I've never made a POST request in one, and don't know what tools I'm using, I'd like to know if someone can help me with some code for this API, I'd like to send a JSON file to this website, with locations and a date. Thank you very much for your answers in advance.

```
This is ha API : 

To be autorized to access the API, you have to send in the header of the request this :
cle : user_key (user_key is the key returned by api https://www.visugpx.com/api/account  when user have been logged in)

Parameters (POST fields)
user_id : the id of the user
shared_id : the id generated when started sharing position [A-Za-z0-9]{4}
frequency : frequency pushing (in seconds)
json  :  the JSON file with lat, lng, altitude, date, starting with the point WITH THE LAST DATE RECIEVED :
[
[45.21406,5.74749,445,"2019-11-05T15:29:45Z"],
[45.21401,5.74752,470,"2019-11-05T15:29:46Z"],
[45.21397,5.74763,472,"2019-11-05T15:29:47Z"],
[45.21393,5.74789,471,"2019-11-05T15:29:48Z"],
[45.21389,5.74849,473,"2019-11-05T15:29:49Z"]
]

example :


curl -X POST -H "cle: 780bf0421d7e962" -F "user_id=47554" -F "shared_id=Ts5z" -F "frequency=60" -F "json=@/path/to/file.json" "https://www.visugpx.com/api/live" 


response (header -> json) :
HTTP/1.0 400 Bad Request -> {"ERROR": "NO USER_ID"}
HTTP/1.0 400 Bad Request -> {"ERROR": "NO USER_KEY"}
HTTP/1.0 400 Bad Request -> {"ERROR": "NOT A VALID USER_KEY"}
HTTP/1.0 400 Bad Request -> {"ERROR": "NO SHARED_ID"}
HTTP/1.0 400 Bad Request -> {"ERROR": "NO FREQUENCY"}
HTTP/1.0 400 Bad Request -> {"ERROR": "NO JSON FILE"}
HTTP/1.0 400 Bad Request -> {"ERROR": "NOT A VALID JSON FILE"}
HTTP/1.0 500 Internal Server Error -> {"ERROR": "SERVER ERROR"}
HTTP/1.0 200 OK -> {"SUCCESS": "2019-11-05T15:29:49Z"}            // the last date recieved.
```

Comment: There are many libraries for REST communication that you can use with Android. The most common is Retrofit: https://square.github.io/retrofit/ There are many examples and tutorials online how to use it.

Comment: Thankyou very much for answer, but if you have some code. It will help me so much... Thank you for every one.

Comment: I need help, please i am beginner...